# How can de Rham cohomology find obstructions?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-fields, fiber-bundles, de-rham-cohomology

A differential form is closed iff its exterior derivative is $0$.
A differential $k$-form $w$ is exact iff there exists a differential $(k-1)$-form $\eta$ so that $\hbox{d}\eta = \omega$.

Every exact differential form is closed, but closed differential forms are only locally exact (Poincare's lemma).

The quotient of closed $k$-forms modulo exact $k$-forms is the $k$-th de Rham cohomology group $H_{\text{dR}}^k(M)$ for some manifold $M$.

What's an example of an obstruction that de Rham cohomology can help identify (and how does it identify it)?

(Possible examples: global integrability of $k$-forms, existence and integrability of vectors fields, existence of circle bundles, existence of fiber bundles, existence of global sections, existence of connections, etc.)

Comment: That's a gigantic question. You'll need to pare it down a lot, to comport with our guidelines to [ask one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671).

Comment: @LeeMosher Okay I've limited it to just one example.

Comment: Betti numbers $\beta_i$ (and thus de Rham cohomology) are used to compute the Euler characteristic $\chi(M) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \beta_i$. It is known that $M$ admits a non-vanishing vector field if and only if $\chi(M) = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of examples, the one I've thought comes from symplectic geometry.

Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold, a 2-form $\omega \in \Omega^2(M)$ is symplectic if it is non-degenerate (so if $\iota_X\omega$ is not the zero form unless $X = 0$) and closed. A symplectic manifold is a pair $(M,\omega)$.

The existence of such a non-degenerate form forces $M$ to be even-dimensional, say $\operatorname{dim}M = 2n$, one can check that non-degeneracy implies that $\omega^n$ is a volume form; in particular it can't be exact. Thus $[\omega]\neq 0$. Reading this reasoning backwards, we find that, if $H_{DR}^2(M) = 0$, then $M$ cannot be symplectic.

Comment: The claim "if $H^1(M) = 0$, then any real vector bundle on $M$ is trivial" is obviously false. Did you mean a "real line bundle"? Or did you mean "orientable" rather than trivial?

Comment: @MoisheKohan yeah sorry. It was a refuse. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: What is $\iota_X \omega$?

Comment: $H^2(M)$, that's the 2nd cohomology group of what cohomology theory?

Comment: @étale-cohomology $\iota_X\omega$ is the contraction of $\omega$ over a vector field $X$